# Why does my network adapter prevent me from seeing active directory accounts?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory

On my windows server 2008 R2 box I have two network adapters.

**Adapter 1:** 
static ip of 192.168.10.12
subnet mask of 255.255.255.0
DNS server at 192.168.10.10

**Adapter 2:** 
gets IP address from DHCP

I can log into this box with active directory accounts without issue.  However, I **cannot** setup any services to run as active directory accounts.  Windows says the account credentials are incorrect.  Now, when I disable Adapter 2, everything works fine.

**Update:**
When I open the "select user, computer, or group" dialog and then click "Locations" this is what I see.

**Adapter 2 off**

```
1) machine name
2) Entire directory
    domain.net
```

**Adapter 2 on**

```
1) machine name
```

**What is it about Adapter 2 that is causing this issue?**

Comment: Is the 2nd NIC on the same subnet as the first? Which subnet has access to AD? How many DCs, what subnets, AD Sites? Is 192.168.10.10 an AD DNS server?

Comment: Is the 2nd NIC on the same subnet as the first? No, its on subnet 255.255.252.0.

Which subnet has access to AD? 255.255.255.0.

How many DCs, what subnets, AD Sites? 1 DC, not sure, not sure.

Is 192.168.10.10 an AD DNS server? yes.

Comment: do a ipconfig on adapter 2 whats the dns settings?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to change the preferred order of the connections? If you go to:

Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings -> Advanced Menu -> Advanced Settings

you will have an option to re-order the connections, make sure that Adapter 1 is first in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but after trying that, it did not fix my problem.